# C# Radio Button Quiz

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a section as part of an application, displaying a question with 3 possible answers in the form of radio buttons.

I have managed to get it to check if Question 1's radio buttons are selected, however when adding 3 more radio buttons for  Question 2, it includes the first 3 radio buttons for the first question.

Is there any way to segregate Question 1's radio buttons from Question 2,3,4,5 etc?

Comment: winforms, webforms, mvc,...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different `GroupBox` for each question and put radio buttons of each question on its respective `GroupBox`. You can accomplish this easily in designer but you could also specify it in code.

Check the image:[image]